# How did the colonists know they wouldn't affect their future?

Tags: time-travel, terra-nova

I'm a little confused. How did the people in the past in *Terra Nova* know they weren't going to alter the future of human race? Or, is it not their past but a whole new planet they colonized?

Comment: I also would like love a season 2 which rumor Netflix may pick up

Answer (score 4):

The past they went to was not the same "timeline" as the future they came from. The technology they use to travel through time allows them to jump to "parallel time streams" at arbitrary points along that timeline.

So, nothing that happened in the past could affect *the colonists* future. It's never really explored what they were doing to *that timeline's* previously-existing future, and if their actions would impact the possible development of human life there.

Comment: "previously-existing future" lol, sci-fi is confusing. :) +1

Comment: To build on this: there's a line (I believe in the first episode) where they mention that a probe was originally sent back through the portal, but they were never able to detect its ancient remains in "present day", so they determined that the portal lead to an alternate timeline.

Comment: Not "arbitrary points along that timeline" at all. They can only travel to one specific point in place and time.